# How to know Placeholder String width in px by Jquery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, placeholder

Here is the html

```
<body style="background-color:#999;font-size:12px;">
    <div style="width:500px; height:500px; margin:30px auto; background-color:#9CC">
    <input id="Test" type='text' placeholder='Hello how are you' style="width:270px;" / >
    </div>
</body>
```

I want to know the text width only.
Not the input width nor the number of character. Please help me with a proper suggestion.

Comment: for width text, you mean at the length or pixels?

Comment: he want the width taken by placeholder text.

Comment: ok, but number of chars ex.(17 characters) or width ex. (100px)?

Comment: @napster3world `How to know Placeholder String width in px`

Comment: pixels @napster3world

Comment: +1 for a great question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use following snippet:

```
var _$tmpSpan = $('<span/>').html($('#Test').attr('placeholder')).css({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: -9999,
    top: -9999
}).appendTo('body'),
    textWidth = _$tmpSpan.width();
_$tmpSpan.remove();
alert(textWidth);
```

### --DEMO--

Comment: brilliant am i right what I think  you just did .Get the place holder text and wrapped it in the span got the width of the span ????

Comment: @user3127499 Ya, that's the idea here. Now, it could be wrong result returned depending any specific CSS rules apply to specific element, e.g, if input has specific font-size set. This could be handled too anyway

Comment: but it showing
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-7ZC0DWrMnDk/U5GpsI0OnNI/AAAAAAAAADk/9GcXnqGTCY8/w1044-h467-no/Capture1.JPG



and I found
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-6ZPcRHem7Eg/U5GpsNh9zBI/AAAAAAAAADg/a2WVkQEbtuQ/w1044-h462-no/Capture.JPG
105px

Comment: yes @A.Wolff you are right. these are different because placeholder CSS and SPAN tag css did not match

Comment: @A.Wolff I just edit your code little bit and find the answer thank you so much
http://jsfiddle.net/goldfingerxyz/FwHg4/